# How to update a nested value within a nested Laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

I have a `deployments` Laravel Collection like this:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#415 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => array:7 [▼
      "id" => 31
      "status" => "active"
      "name" => "Deployment 1"
      "spots" => array:4 [▼
        0 => array:2 [▼
          "id" => 33
          "status" => "active"            <-- Want to change this
        ]
        1 => array:2 [▶]
        2 => array:2 [▶]
        3 => array:2 [▶]
      ]
      "data" => array:3 [▶]
    ]
    1 => array:7 [▶]
    2 => array:7 [▶]
    3 => array:7 [▶]
    4 => array:7 [▶]
  ]
}
```

I want to update the nested `status` value to `inactive`. I have used the Laravel `map` function, but it only seems to work on collections that have one nesting level. So this...

```
$this->deployments->map(function ($deployment) {
    $deployment['spots'][0]['status'] = 'inactive';
});
dd($this->deployments);
```

...leaves `$this->deployments` untouched.

Also tried using nested `map` functions obtaining a `Call to a member function map() on array` exception on second level as second and next nesting levels are considered arrays...

Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `map` method, you are almost there. You will have to *return* the change made in `$deployment` and do an `->all()` at the end to update the collection with the modified values.

**For updating a single spot:**

```
$deployments = $deployments->map(function($deployment){
    $deployment['spots'][0]['status'] = 'inactive';
    return $deployment;
  })->all();
```

**For updating all spots:**

```
$deployments = $deployments->map(function($deployment){
    foreach($deployment['spots'] as &$spot){
      $spot['status'] = 'inactive';
    }
    return $deployment;
  })->all();
```

Comment: Thank you! It works as expected. But it works even without the `->all()` portion at the end.

Comment: For someone in the same situation: it was a noob mistake, I was forgeting the `return` statement in the `map` function. The `->all()` portion is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone researching this, a more elegant solution might be:

**For updating a single spot:**

```
$data = $deployments->all();
$deployments = data_set($data, 'spots.0.status', 'inactive');
```

**For updating all spots:**

```
$data = $deployments->all();
$deployments = data_set($data, 'spots.*.status', 'inactive');
```